# Formatting the date in JSP

Tags: html, jsp, date-formatting

I have one jsp file with the following content

```
<span class = "inlineError" ng-if = "isFutureEffectiveDate('ADDRESS')">
                 Effective : {{page.data.effectiveDateMap["ADDRESS"]}}
                </span>
```

The page.data.effectiveDateMap["ADDRESS"] is returning a date and I need to format it in 'MMM/DD/YYYY' format. How can I do that?

Comment: The `ng-if` directive implies you are using AngularJS. And yet you are asking about JSP. You sure?